# Anylogic Pedestrian Queue and Service Points

Tags: queue, anylogic, agent, population

I have a model representing people arriving to security control. There is a **queue** in front of the building where **the security control** is held. In this building, I have several queues based on pedestrians' parameters (nationality, age,...) and I have a problem that once the queue in the building is full and the time spent in queue increases, the **pedestrians** **waiting** in the queue outside start to walk away or in opposite direction and they actually enter the model several times...which causes inadequate outputs in time spent in a queue...

Can anyone please give me I hint on how to solve it? I need them to wait in a **queue** outside until the queue inside has space for them...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best model it like this: have an outside queue and an inside queue, separated by enough space.

Add a "Hold" object (from the process modelling library) in between them and use it to manually "let through" 1 pedestrian from the outside queue once the inside queue has space.

Check example models and the help to learn more about the "Hold" element, really useful to use here